# BoxConstraint is giving a negative min height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to animate my logo using the Animation.curve but when I use Curves.elasticInOut I get an error saying
"BoxConstraints has a negative minimum height."... please help

```
class InitState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
```

late AnimationController _controller;
late Animation _animation;

```
void initState() {
super.initState();

_controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));

_animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticInOut);

_controller.forward();

_animation.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    startTimer();
  }
});

_controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {});
});



Widget initWidget() {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xff0d0d0d),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              (Color(0xff3F3F3F)),
              (Color(0xff2D2D2D)),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: _animation.value * 100,
          child: Image.asset('assets/images/foodie_logo.png'),//This is where I get the error
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves/elasticInOut-constant.html) of the `Curves.elasticInOut` animation, you can see that the value can be negative :

[image]

Change the animation by another one with non-negative value :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html

Comment: so what if I wanna use this one... how do I make the value negative...

Comment: You have to prevent the _animation.value to be negative. You can do that like this : `(_animation.value < 0 ? 0 :  _animation.value)`

Comment: Ok, hope that will help you ! If it is, don't forget to accept my answer ;) Thx